# Python - converting to binary a colour image using intermediate values

Tags: python, image, colors, binary, boolean

I would like to take a colour image and convert it to a binary image where what was close to either black or white return False, and all the intermediate values return True.

What is the proper syntax to impose the two conditions below simultaneously?

```
binary = color.rgb2gray(img) > 0.05 
binary = color.rgb2gray(img) < 0.95
```

If I used this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import color
import requests
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

url = 'https://mycarta.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/spectrogram_jet.png'
r = requests.get(url)
img = np.asarray(Image.open(StringIO(r.content)).convert('RGB'))
```

and then:

```
binary = color.rgb2gray(img)  < 0.95
```

I would get a proper binary image that I can plot with:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(binary, cmap='gray')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
plt.show()
```

Similarly with this:

```
color.rgb2gray(img) < 0.95
```

But if I tried them together like this:

```
binary = color.rgb2gray(img) > 0.05 and color.rgb2gray(img) < 0.95
```

I got this message:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What code did you run to "try them together"?

Comment: Same as suggested in @caenyon's answer: binary = color.rgb2gray(img) > 0.05 and color.rgb2gray(img) < 0.95

Comment: what is the img variable? an complete example would be easier (imports etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working because the `rgb2gray` method of `skimage.color` returns an array. The `skimage` module utilizes the `numpy` module which refuses to perform boolean comparisons on arrays. This is where your `ValueError` comes from.

When using a comparison operator like `and` on arrays, `numpy` will not comply. Instead, you should use `np.logical_and` or the binary operator `&`.

Comment: your suggestion worked, thank you for the explanation too

Answer (score -1):

you can use 'and' to combine these two conditions

```
binary = color.rgb2gray(img) > 0.05 and color.rgb2gray(img) < 0.95
```

or you can just write them as one condition

```
binary = 0.05 < color.rgb2gray(img) < 0.95
```

Comment: When I try those two options you suggest, in both cases (the first one is what I tried before) I get the error message

Comment: what exactly does the color.rgb2gray function return? are you sure that it's a number and not a list?

Comment: how does the rest of your program look like? i'd assume that the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: color.rgb2gray(img) just applies the formula Y = (0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B) to convert to gray

Comment: The code is very simple. This works:
binary = color.rgb2gray(img)  < 0.95   
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))   
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)   
plt.imshow(binary, cmap='gray')   
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks([])   
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks([])   
plt.show()

Comment: please edit your first post and add additional information / code to your problem. otherwise i can only guess what's going wrong.